# What is default mode of operation DESede algorithm uses in Java

Tags: java, encryption

This is how I am creating cipher instance

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
```

Comment: **Do not use DES for new work**, it is no longer considered secure and has been superceeded by AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) DES only has key size is only 56 bits which is not considered to be secure, AES supports key sizes of 128,192 and 256 bits. See [Security comparison of DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26181/5121).

Answer (score 2):

There is no single, universal, default mode. For example, if I recall correctly, the Oracle providers default to ECB mode and the providers on Android default to CBC mode. That's why you should *always* specify the full "algorithm/mode/padding" string in the `Cipher.getInstance()` method. Otherwise you risk unexpected and non-portable behavior.